# Prove that $T$ is one-to-one iff $T$ carries linearly independent subsets of $V$ onto lineraly independent subsets of $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $T:V\rightarrow W$ be linear.

(a) Prove that $T$ is one-to-one iff $T$ carries linearly independent subsets of $V$ onto linearly independent subsets of $W$.

(b) Suppose that $T$ is one-to-one and that $S$ is a subset of $V$. Prove that $S$ is linear independent iff $T(S)$ is linear independent.

(c) Suppose $\mathcal{B} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $T$ is one-to-one and onto. Prove that $T(\mathcal{B}) = \{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2}),\ldots,T(v_{n})\}$ is a basis for $W$.

**MY ATTEMPT (EDIT)**

(a) We shall prove that implication ($\Rightarrow$) first.

Suppose that $S = \{s_{1},s_{2},\ldots,s_{m}\}\subset V$ is linear independent and $T$ is injective. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
& a_{1}T(s_{1}) + a_{2}T(s_{2}) + \ldots + a_{m}T(s_{m}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& T(a_{1}s_{1} + a_{2}s_{2} + \ldots + a_{m}s_{m}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{1}s_{1} + a_{2}s_{2} + \ldots + a_{m}s_{m} = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{1} = a_{2} = \ldots = a_{m} = 0
\end{align*}

Thus $\{T(s_{1}),T(s_{2}),\ldots,T(s_{m})\}$ is linear independent, just as it has been claimed.

Let us prove that $(\Leftarrow)$ holds too.

We must prove that $T(v) = 0$ implies that $v = 0$. Indeed, according to the given assumption, if $\mathcal{B}_{V} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $T(\mathcal{B}_{V}) = \{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2}),\ldots,T(v_{n})\}$ is linear independent. Thence we get that
\begin{align*}
& T(v) = T(a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + a_{n}v_{n}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{1}T(v_{1}) + a_{2}T(v_{2}) + \ldots + a_{n}T(v_{n}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{1} = a_{2} = \ldots = a_{n} = 0 \Longrightarrow v = 0
\end{align*}
and we are done.

(b) Let us prove $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

If $S$ is LI, then $T(S)$ is LI, according to (a).

Let us now prove the implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

If $S = \{s_{1},s_{2},\ldots,s_{n}\}$, then $T(S) = \{T(s_{1}),T(s_{2}),\ldots,T(s_{n})\}$. If $T(S)$ is LI, then one has that
\begin{align*}
& a_{1}s_{1} + a_{2}s_{2} + \ldots + a_{n}s_{n} = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& T(a_{1}s_{1} + a_{2}s_{2} + \ldots + a_{n}s{n}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{1}T(s_{1}) + a_{2}T(s_{2}) + \ldots + a_{n}T(s_{n}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& a_{1} = a_{2} = \ldots = a_{n} = 0
\end{align*}
Thus $S$ is linear independent, just as desired.

(c) If $T$ is one-to-one, then $T(\mathcal{B}) = \{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2}),\ldots,T(v_{n})\}$ is linear independent. This is because $\mathcal{B}$ is LI as well.

Since $T$ is onto, we have that $T(V) = \text{span}(T(\mathcal{B})) = W$. Consequently, $T(\mathcal{B})$ is a basis for $W$, and we are done.

Could someone double-check my arguments?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read one to one and onto. I just read one to one.

Comment: For the second part of (a): if $T(v)=0$, that means that $\{T(v)\}$ is *not* linearly independent.

Comment: For the backwards direction, you want to show that kerT consists of the zero vector. To do this, you must show that if $v\in kerT$ then $v=0$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To prove that $T$ is injective is the same as to prove that it is non-singular, that is to say, $T(v) = 0$ implies that $v = 0$.

Comment: @BrickByBrick: I am aware of that; but you are trying to use the fact that $T$ sends linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets in order to show that. The point is that if $T(v)=0$, then the set $\{T(v)\}$ is linearly **dependent**; what does that tell you about the set $\{v\}$?

Comment: Now I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your revised attempt to show that if $T$ sends linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets is correct as far as it goes. It suffers form an unwarranted assumption that your space is finite dimensional (though you are probably working just with finite dimensional spaces). This can easily be fixed by taking an arbitrary basis and then just taking finitely many basis vectors needed to express $v$.

But there is a much simpler way: it is enough to show that if $v\neq 0$ then $T(v)\neq 0$. If $v\neq 0$, then $\{v\}$ is linearly independent, hence $\{T(v)\}$ is linearly independent; hence $T(v)\neq 0$.

Alternatively, using contrapositives, if $T(v)=0$ then $\{T(v)\}$ is linearly **dependent**, which means that $\{v\}$ is linearly dependent, which means that $v=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The first half of your argument for (a) is fine. The second half, however, is not: your $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ come out of thin air and have no apparent connection with $v$, the vector assumed to be in $\ker T$. I suggest that you assume instead that $T$ is not one-to-one and find a linearly independent set whose image under $T$ is not linearly independent.

One direction of (b) is an application of (a), but the other is not: you still have to show that if $T(S)$ is linearly independent, then so is $S$.

Your argument for (c) is fine.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the comments. I have fixed my arguments and provided a full answer to (b) as suggested. Could you please double-check if I am reasoning rightly this time?